# Array initialisation with value

Tags: php

Hello guys i have coded something like this ..I just dont know wheather the code is right or not ..But i have a question

THe code is

```
$featured = array('name' => 12,'yeah' => 10);
foreach($featured as $key => $value){
  echo $value['name'];
}
```

I know that value of name can be acessed by $featured['name']
 but now I just need to know wheather the key of array can be acessed with value like $value['name'].
Is it possbile like that ?..

Any help would be appreciated ..Thanks

Comment: What do you think `$key` is in your `foreach()` loop? - http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$featured = array('name' => 12,'yeah' => 10);
foreach($featured as $key => $value){
  echo $key; // outputs: name
  echo " - ";
  echo $value; // outputs: 12
  echo "<br />";
}
```

Yes, it supports that in the next iteration of the loop.

Output:

```
name - 12
yeah - 10
```

BTW, one more way of accessing the [key](http://php.net/key)s from array.

```
$featured = array('name' => 12,'yeah' => 10);
while (current($featured)) {
  echo key($featured).'<br />';
  next($featured);
}
```

Output:

```
name
yeah
```

Comment: then how to execute yeah key and 10 value ?

Comment: will it support the both name=>12 and yeah=>10 according to ur code ?

Answer (score 1):

You most probably want to do:

```
echo "{$key} => {$value}";
```

The `foreach($featured as $key => $value)` statement iterates the `array` and for each iteration `$key` and `$value` contain both the key and value for the tuple.

Comment: ma qus in not like that ..i just need to know wheather can we acess name key like $value['name'] ?

Comment: No, but you can access it as `$featured['name']`;

Comment: No, `PHP` does not support that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:
http://php.net/array_search
it searches for the value and returns it's key.

It's not like accessing $array['value'] but it's still userfull if you want to find the key.